# css top-menu not staying in hovered style when cursor moved to sub-menus

Tags: css, menu, hover, submenu

I have a top menu bar and when the mouse hovers over each menu item it turns purple.

One of these menus also has a drop down list of further items. When I move the mouse cursor down through these sub-menus the top menu goes back to the original style. I would like it to stay purple even when I am hovering over the sub-menu items. Website is [here](http://mhyoga-test.weebly.com/), if you hover over sub-menu under "About" it shows the problem.

I have searched through a few similar stackoverflow answers. For example this problem and [previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106650/css-menu-keep-parent-hovered-while-focus-on-submenu). I tried a change from this

```
#topnav li a:hover {}
```

to

```
#topnav li hover:a {}
```

But neither this suggested change or the original keeps the top menu purple. Full code below:

```
#topnav {
    clear: both;
    background: url(nav-bg-orange.png) no-repeat;
    height: 87px;
    width: 962px;
    padding: 6px 63px 6px;
}

#topnav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

#topnav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    border-left: 1px dashed #f38739;
}

#topnav ul li:last-child {
     border-right: 1px dashed #f38739;
 }

#topnav ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#topnav li#active a,
#topnav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #745b7c;
    display:block;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}


/****************************** flyout menus ******************************/

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #745b7c;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #9e89a4;
}

#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #8c7395;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the html as well..?

Comment: Have you tried `#topnav ul:hover`?

Comment: any jsfiddle available?

Comment: There is nothing like this: `#topnav li hover:a {` you have to write this like this : `#topnav li a:hover {}` and then try

Comment: @simpe #topnav ul:hover. Just makes the whole of the top navigation row become selected.

Comment: @Joy_S I did use #topnav li a:hover {} previously, but I changed it, due seeing it as another answer to same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106650/css-menu-keep-parent-hovered-while-focus-on-submenu). Changing it back to #topnav li a:hover {} still has the same problem.

Comment: Okay, now what do you want ? do you want to show the same hover effect like the main navigation items in the sub menu ? I am not clear this still.

Comment: @Joy_S Sorry not doing a good job of explaining. I have edited the original question again to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: I think it should work but if it doesn't work then you can use jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a friend to take a look at this for me. In ordre to fix the menus I needed to change the javascript that currently animates the sub-menus. Unfortunately, because I'm using a Weebly based template I can't access this code to change it. So looks like a dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting your

```
#wsite-menus
```

menu nested in element with class

```
.wsite-nav-3
```

In that case it should work correctly.

```
<li id="pg524622535697207710" class="wsite-nav-3" style="position: relative;"><a href="/about.html" style="position: relative;">About </a><div id="wsite-menus"><div class="wsite-menu-wrap" style="position: absolute; left: -1118px; display: block; top: 47px;"><ul class="wsite-menu" style="display: block;"><li id="wsite-nav-977240454937878932" style="position: relative;"><a href="/hatha-yoga.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Hatha Yoga</span></a></li><li id="wsite-nav-788960178245244400" style="position: relative;"><a href="/yin-yoga.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Yin Yoga</span></a></li><li id="wsite-nav-226130023988115977" style="position: relative;"><a href="/yoga-for-men.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Yoga for Men</span></a></li><li id="wsite-nav-104813911397431638" style="position: relative;"><a href="/prenatel-yoga.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Prenatel Yoga</span></a></li><li id="wsite-nav-176000207649938754" style="position: relative;"><a href="/private-classes.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Private Classes</span></a></li><li id="wsite-nav-558168910269966978" style="position: relative;"><a href="/yoga-for-business.html" style="position: relative;"><span class="wsite-menu-title">Yoga for Business</span></a></li></ul></div></div> </li>
```

I haven't checked it on my own, but there's a good chance it's OK.

Answer (score -1):

Excuse me. Are you new to CSS?
All you have to do is use UL:HOVER. That's because you're removing your mouse from the LI. So use UL as the trigger. Even if you change LIs, the UL won't go off. :)

Comment: Yes new! Using ul:Hover makes all of the top navigation menu become selected, I'm afraid. Just tried it. I'm trying to make the top menu of the particular sub-menu stay selected even when the mouse moves to these lower level LIs.