# add css to hover menu parent but not child

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to do something similar to this: [CSS Menu - Keep parent hovered while focus on submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106650/css-menu-keep-parent-hovered-while-focus-on-submenu)
im using !important to override bootstrap colors
it works for the parent but i dont want the child li>a to be effected

.hover-li:hover a{

```
color: blue !important;
}

.hover-li ul li  {
    color: white !important;
}
```

the structure is like this:

```
<li class = "hover-li">
<a></a>
<ul>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: ditch the important and add :hover to the second selector....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.hover-li:hover > a {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

it only affects direct children